# Python Nested For Loops and MultiThreading

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, for-loop

I've used multithreading before with python, however for whatever reason, I can't seem to find a functioning solution to create a properly working script that fits my needs. In this script I'm writing, I have two lists that I am trying to merge and manipulate into one list. I am writing the lists to text files at a predetermined amount of lines "1,000,000 lines".

The issue that comes up when making it mulitithreading is that the variable i'm using to count the lines of the list "text_amount" isn't counting them properly. And after the first rotation of the second for loop is goes back to zero. I'm not sure if this is a logic based error, I'm using global variables incorrectly, or I need to use another threading method. Any feedback from you guys would be very much appreciated.

Here is my script without mulitithreading:

```
thelist = []
text_amount = 0
filenumber = 0

for text2 in file2:
    for text1 in file1:
        if both word fit certain criteria:
            word = text1 + text2
            thelist.extend(word)
            text_amount += 1
        if text_amount >= 1000000:
            filenumber += 1
            text_amount = 0
            print ("Saved File " + str(filenumber))
            outputName =  str(filenumber)
            savefilefunction(outputName, thelist)
            thelist = []
#amends the last unsaved lines          
filenumber += 1
outputName =  str(filenumber)
savefilefunction(outputName, thelist)
```

Here is my attempt at mulitithreading:

```
def together(text1,text2):
    global filenumber
    global text_amount
    global thelist
    if both word fit certain criteria:
            word = text1 + text2
            thelist.extend(word)
            text_amount += 1
    if filenumber >= 1000000:
        filenumber += 1
        text_amount = 0
        print("Saved File " + str(text_amount))
        outputName = outName + "-" + str(text_amount) + ".txt"
        savefilefunction(outputName, thelist)
        thelist = []



global fileNameNumber
global fileNumber
global keywordList
thelist = []
text_amount = 0
filenumber = 0
for text2 in file2:
    for text1 in file1:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            future_results = {executor.submit(together, text1,text2): text1 for text1 in file1}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_results):
                future.result()


filenumber += 1
outputName =  str(filenumber)
savefilefunction(outputName, thelist)
```

Comment: Why do you declare the global vars inside the function and outside of it?

Comment: Honestly, I was just trying to bruteforce my way into making this code work, I haven't used global variables in python before so I was just trying anything. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: I would try removing this piece of code
 `global filenumber
  global text_amount
  global thelist` 
from the beginning of function def

Comment: If I do that the variables are unresolved. The only place I can take it off is within the second part.

Comment: i'm noob here but I think what you want to look at is numba library, example; for i in numba.prange(len(file.readlines())